# Java: Is it possible to record audio from the sound card output (speakers)?

Tags: java

What I'm trying now (don't mind about the syntax - it's Kotlin):

```
audioFormat = AudioFormat(8000f, 8, 2, true, false)

mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()
mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[0]) // have tried all

dataLineInfo = DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine::class.java, audioFormat)
dataLine = mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo) as TargetDataLine // IllegalArgumentException

dataLine.open()
dataLine.start()
AudioSystem.write(AudioInputStream(dataLine), AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, File("1.wav"))
```

Unfortunatelly a `IllegalArgumentException` is being thrown at `mixer.getLine`:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian

I've tried all the available mixers and audio formats. Still no luck. The only working mixer is the microphone mixer. All the output-mixers cause the exception.

I've also tried to detect supported audio formats using `AudioSystem.isLineSupported`, but I coudn't detect any single format that would be supported by output-mixers. `AudioSystem.isLineSupported` always returns `false` for all the possible formats I've checked.

So, is it possible to record the sound I hear from speakers?

---

PS: There is some capture soft that can perform such record. For example, SnagIt 12 can record audio from my sound card. And there are lot of similar apps.

Comment: I think the newer soundcards don't support that any more, to make it harder to copy streaming data. If I realy need to i make a shortcut from out to in/microphone with a cable.

Comment: @Turo But such software EXISTS. For example, SnagIt 12 can easily record audio from my sound card. And there are lot of similar apps.